# React: How can you access the class name of a parent component from a child without passing it down as props?

Tags: reactjs

Say you have a parent component:

```
// ParentComponent

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <ChildComponent/>
    )
  }
}
```

From inside the child component, is there a way to access the class name of the parent component without passing this down as props?

```
// ChildComponent

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

  // ?????
  getParentComponentName() {
    return this.???  // Should return "ParentComponent"
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div/>
    )
  }
}
```

I'd prefer to be able to access this without passing it down as props. Thank you!

Comment: Event if it is possible without passing as props, you should not do it

Comment: why don't you go with static, I mean you can create a static function in parent component and use it in child component.

Comment: Can you please share the usecase here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access `ReactInternalFiber` like

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: '' }
    }
    getParentName = () =>{
        this.setState({ name: this._reactInternalFiber._debugOwner.type.name })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Name: {this.state.name}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.getParentName}>Get Parent Name</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Edit Parent & Child Components]